# Htaccess - Drop part of URL when condition matches

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to drop ?mfp= (and anything after it), provided the URL contains /designs/ in it. So for example, these..

```
https://www.example.com/designs/upload-your-own/?mfp=30o-color%5B112%5D&tag=hoodies
https://www.example.com/designs/upload-your-own/?mfp=60o-type%5B191%5D%2C30o-color%5B112%5D&tag=hoodies
https://www.example.com/designs/upload-your-own/?mfp=manufacturers%5B43%5D%2C60o-type%5B191%5D%2C30o-color%5B112%5D&tag=hoodies
https://www.example.com/designs/upload-your-own/?mfp=c-categories-0%5B305%5D&tag=hoodies
```

..will become:

```
https://www.example.com/designs/upload-your-own/
https://www.example.com/designs/upload-your-own/
https://www.example.com/designs/upload-your-own/
https://www.example.com/designs/upload-your-own/
```

But something like:

```
https://www.example.com/hoodies/?mfp=c-categories-0[305],manufacturers[43],60o-type[191],30o-color[112]
```

..will remain untouched (since it doesn't have /designs/ in the URL).

Thanks!

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as first rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mfp= [NC]
RewriteRule ^designs/ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,NC,R=301,NE]

# your remaining rules
```

`?` at the end of target URI will strip off any query string from original URI.

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! Once again, you are a guru at htaccess and this worked perfectly :)